# How to get dynamic value from View in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am coming across a scenario where I need to do something in the viewmodel according to the current selection in the view, but according to MVVM, the view model should not know about the existence of view, then how can i get the dynamic selection in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Josh Smith's Article on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

> Unlike the Presenter in MVP, a
>   ViewModel does not need a reference to
>   a view. The view binds to properties
>   on a ViewModel, which, in turn,
>   exposes data contained in model
>   objects and other state specific to
>   the view.

Hence you can have a property in your ViewModel and bind it to the ListView's SelectedItem.